# List of algorithms also shows appendices in latex document

Tags: latex

I'm using my university template for my thesis, I have some algorithms and appendices. The template defines a new command for the appendices "anexos" and a listofanexos list them. The problem is that the appendices are listed in the same list of the algorithms using the command "listofalgorithms". If I place the command "\listofanexos" first, then the appendices and algorithms are shown in listofanexos. If I place "\listofalgorithms" first, then the appendices and algorithms are shown in the list of algorithms. Here a simple example that shows the problem

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt,english]{report}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listanexosname}{\hfill\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries List of Appendices}
\newlistof[chapter]{anexos}{loa}{\listanexosname}
\newcommand{\anexos}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{anexos}
\par\noindent\textbf{Appendix \Alph{anexos}. #1}
\addcontentsline{loa}{anexos}{\protect\numberline{\Alph{anexos}}#1}\par
}
\begin{document} 
\title{My work}
\listofalgorithms
\listofanexos

\chapter{Test}
This is a test

\begin{algorithm}[!b]
\caption{My algorithm}\label{alg:binaryPCA}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $\Sigma_1 = m$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\newpage
%\nnchapter{Appendices}
\anexos{My appendix}\label{anexoA} 
This is a test
\section*{Test section}
Some text here

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `algorithm` package also uses the file ending `.loa` to store its list of algorithms. You can avoid the problem by using some other name for your list of appendices:

```
\documentclass[letter,12pt,english]{report}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listanexosname}{\hfill\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries List of Appendices}
\newlistof[chapter]{anexos}{loaa}{\listanexosname}
\newcommand{\anexos}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{anexos}
\par\noindent\textbf{Appendix \Alph{anexos}. #1}
\addcontentsline{loaa}{anexos}{\protect\numberline{\Alph{anexos}}#1}\par
}
\begin{document} 
\title{My work}
\listofalgorithms
\listofanexos

\chapter{Test}
This is a test

\begin{algorithm}[!b]
\caption{My algorithm}\label{alg:binaryPCA}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $\Sigma_1 = m$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\newpage
%\nnchapter{Appendices}
\anexos{My appendix}\label{anexoA} 
This is a test
\section*{Test section}
Some text here

\end{document}
```